# Only logged in admin should access frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, access

I want to set restriction to access frontend for users that are not logged-in to admin panel (same browser or not).
Means user who is not logged in admin panel should not access frontend and should be redirected maintenance page.

I think it's possible by IP Address by editing `index.php`.

Comment: If you want it for different brwosers, you should go with Princes solution ... otherwise my answer should also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below free extension which will fulfill your requirement.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/maintenance-mode-4.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-site-maintenance.html

These extensions have a facility to set admin access so if admin will be logged in he may access frontend, other users will be redirected to a maintenance page.

Hope it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried first extension you suggest

Answer (score 1):

Please try this ... add a custom module with this code:

> app/code/local/My/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <my_module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </my_module>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <check_admin_logged_in>
                        <class>my_module/observer</class>
                        <method>checkAdminIsLoggedIn</method>
                    </check_admin_logged_in>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php

class My_Module_Model_Test extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer
{
    public function checkAdminIsLoggedIn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $page  = 'about-magento-demo-store'; 
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
            $aliases = $controller->getRequest()->getAliases();
            if ($aliases['rewrite_request_path'] != $page) {
                $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($controller->getRequest()->getBaseUrl() . '/' . $page);
                $controller->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Note:*** you have to create a new "CMS Page" and adjust following line for your URL key:

```
$page  = 'about-magento-demo-store';
```

---

You can also try this free extension: https://github.com/astorm/Magento_CrossAreaSessions

Answer (score -1):

1) You have to create an empty `maintenance.flag` file and upload it to the **root folder** of your site. After that your web site will have some message like:`The server is temporarily unable to service...`

2) open the `index.php` file and add this code on line **47**:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$allowed = array('69.65.23.100','2.2.2.2'); //list of IP that will have access to frontend
```

3) replace

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
```

With

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
```

**Nb:** You can edit the message maintenance displayed in `errors/default/503.phtml`

Comment: NO,
I want to set restriction for access front-end who is not logged-in to admin panel

Comment: You said in title `Only logged in admin should access to the frontend`

Comment: Yes,exactly. Your code is only for specific IP Address Which i know already.

Comment: before it was logged in and now is not logged in ;)